# How to add scopes to LinkedIn provider class in Laravel socialite without touching vendors folder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, linkedin-api, laravel-socialite

I have connected LinkedIn using [Laravel socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) but I need extra scopes than the default ones shipped with the socialite package like protected `'rw_company_admin'`.

Laravel ships with `protected $scopes = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress'];` in the `LinkedInProvider.php` file in `/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two`.

How can I add my additional scopes without touching the vendors folder?

Comment: Do you found a solution ?

Comment: Nope due to lack of time I just put the extra scopes into `LinkedInProvider.php`